# Angular 5 - Convert just Array inside FirebaseListObservable

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular5, observable

I am trying to handle only one item from my FirebaseListObservable called `fichas`, converting it from Array to String, but it is not having any effect over `snapshot`.

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

  fichas: FirebaseListObservable<Fichas[]>;

  this.fichas.subscribe((snapshots) => {
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
          snapshot.combustivel.join(" "); //==> this changes nothing!
          this.data.push(snapshot);                  
        });
      })
  console.log(this.data);
}
```

Fichas.ts (class):

```
export class Fichas {
    $key                  : string;
    ativo                 : boolean;
    fabricante            : string;
    nome                  : string;
    ano_fabr              : string;
    ano_model             : string;
    tipo_motor            : string;
    outro_tipo_motor      : string;
    ciclo_motor           : string;
    combustivel           : string[];
    ...
}
```

Currently, it displays as `combustivel: (2) ["Gasolina", "Etanol"]`on console, but I need something like `combustivel: "Gasolina Etanol"`.

The other elements can not be changed, only this one.

Comment: provide your htmi, it might be simpler to address it there as it is presentation you are after not the data model

Comment: @Vivek sorry, but these data are to export an Excel file. I need to convert this particular field to string because the XLSX package does not export more complex data.

Answer (score 0):

.join does not change the array that was joined, but returns a string instead. So, simply change the object in place and push it:

```
snapshot.combistivel = snapshot.combustivel.join(" ");
this.data.push(snapshot);
```

update your definition accordingly:

```
export class Fichas {
...
combustivel           : string[] || string;
...
```

}

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I need to do `push` in all items (are 65 items in total), not just the combustivel item. The `data` must contain every `snapshot`, but only the `snapshot.combustivel` needs to be changed.

Comment: hi @Atoyansk I've updated my answer, just assign the result of the join back to the original object....

Comment: there is an error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`. I just updated my question with another relevant information: in class **Fichas.ts**, `combustivel: string[];`.